# Conflicting types for 'time' when archiving

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native, php-ziparchive

file **crypt.h**:

i was getting in debug mode:

> Conflicting types for 'time'
>
> Implicit declaration of function 'time' is invalid in C99

i solved it by adding:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
```

now i am getting the same error when archiving

i tried to add:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

but nothing is working!